# Visusal Basic Script: Trying to obtain comments/description dll information

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I have a question that pertains to scripting.  For the sake of clarity I'll just start off with a bit of what I'm trying to do.  We have a number of testing environments and projects going on in each environment that trying to keep track of what is where is becoming increasingly difficult.

In order to try and straighten this out I was going to create a script that would pull the comments/description (that is where our developers put the code branch,project name,and date of the build into.  This is what we use for versioning) of the dll.  Then I would dump this information into a simple table on an html page which would be pulled as a web part.

I was using VBS to perform this and I was able to successfully pull a version number and dump it into an HTML page.  However, I have not been able to find any information on how to do this for the comments or description (using Server 2k3 and 2k8) fields.

So my question is if there is a way to pull this information using VBS, or would there be a better scripting language that would allow this to be done.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think exactly what you're asking for is possible, however this may be helpful:

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/filesfolders/files/

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  I will give a few of these a try and see if it works.